# Python - Getting rid of unnecessary output

Tags: python, bash

I am logging into a remote node using SSH, getting the status of a service and want to print it.

Running the bash command on my remote node yields.

```
[root@redis-1 ~]# redis-cli -a '!t3bmjEJss' info replication | grep role | cut -d':' -f2
slave
```

The python code that Ive written is

```
def serviceDetails(ip,svc):
    if svc == 'redis-server':
       ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % ip, "redis-cli -a '!t3Z9LJt2_wmUDbmjEJss' info replication | grep role | cut -d':' -f2"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
       result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
       print (result)
    else:
       print ("Redis service is not running on this node")
```

The output that I am getting from `result` variable is:

```
[b'slave\r\n']
```

Why do all these extra characters appear ? And how can I get rid of them ?

Comment: `result = result.encode('utf-8').strip()`

Comment: @zondo Is this for a list ? Cause right now Im getting 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
. result is a list.

Comment: I'm sorry, no. That's for each line in `stdout`. You would want `result = [line.encode('utf-8').strip() for line in result]`

Comment: @zondo This approach works perfectly fine with python v2.7 but fails with v3.4 . Im trying to run it with 3.4 and get this error AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Ah, encoding and decoding are too confusing. I meant `.decode()`, not `.encode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire process of calling `subprocess.Popen` and then manually reading from its `stdout` property can be condensed into one call which will also automatically performs the bytes to string conversion:

```
subprocess.check_output([arg0, arg1, ...], encoding='utf-8')
```

If you also want to read stderr, then include a `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.

You can find the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) for `subprocess.check_output`  here.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `.readlines()`, it will return a list of lines. You can use `.read()` if you want it all in one string. It has the b there because it is a byte string. To get it to a normal string, you can use `.decode('utf-8')` in most cases. It may be a different encoding, but utf-8 will probably work. Then to get rid of the new line, you can use `.strip()`. Putting it all together, either of these would work:

```
result = ssh.stdout.read().decode('utf-8').strip()
print(result)
# slave
```

or

```
result = [line.decode('utf-8').strip() for line in ssh.stdout.readlines()]
print(result)
# ['slave']
```

Either one will work when you have only one line. If you have more than one line, the first will not work properly; it will have `\r\n` in the middle of the string.